# How not to show zero while retrieving a value in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have an excel file in which i have two sheets. Sheet 1 named "cert" which is a certificate which retrieves and displays value from sheet 2 (lets say sheet 2 as Oct). Sheet 2 "Oct" is like following:

```
          MT       MMBTU
Date1   value1     value1     
        value2     value2
        value3     value3
Date2   value1     value1     
        value2     value2
        value3     value3
```

Each day have 3 values each and it will continue till the last date of the month.
And my sheet 1 "cert" which retrieves value from sheet "Oct" looks like following:

```
   MT:   value 1      value2      value3
MMBTU:   value 1      value2      value3
```

Sheet "Oct" have formula for finding MMBTU from MT. So each time a value is entered in MT, MMBTU will appear in respective cell. My issue here is as the MMBTU coloumn has formula in it, zeros will be appearing in each cell and when MT value is entered, zero will replaced by value. In sheet "cert" i am retrieving last entered values for MT & MMBTU. Values for last entered MT is appearing correctly but for MMBTU it is displaying zero because the coloumn from which the value are being retrieved has been already filled with zeros from the formula (formula which converts MT to MMBTU). How to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `MT:` is in `A1` and `Date1` is in A2, maybe in B2 and copied across to D2:

```
=INDIRECT("Oct!"&ADDRESS(MATCH(LOOKUP(1E+100,Oct!$B:$B),Oct!$B:$B,0)-4+COLUMN(),3))
```